# PowerMokito doNothing() on private setter NullPointer

Tags: junit, powermock

Issue: Nullpointer exception thrown when attempting to execute PowerMockito.doNothing().

I need to create a partialMockObject class that will return a private method value and do nothing for another private setter method.

I am able to make it work if I replace doNothing() with supress() but would like to figure this out.

Code:

```
@Test
public void testPowerMockito() throws Exception
{       

    final String methodName1 = "Method1";
    final String methodName2 = "Method2";

    //Using PowerMockito
    ObjectToTest partialMockObject = PowerMockito.spy(new ObjectToTest());

    //Mock the private method, expect that a false
    PowerMockito.doReturn(false).when( partialMockObject,methodName1 );

    //Do Nothing on the void private setter     
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when( ObjectToTest.class,methodName2 );

    String result = partialMockObject.methodToTest();

    assertEquals("Fail","",result);

    //Confirms that the private method was called
    PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(partialMockObject).invoke(methodName1);
    PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(partialMockObject).invoke(methodName1);

}
```

StackTrace:
'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:68)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:43)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:104)

Answer (score 1):

I have used PowerMockito extensively to try and deal with writing unit tests on some tricky legacy Java code.  The best I can tell you is that not everything you think should work will work and that the online examples are of mixed age and quality.  The spy works for doing the verifyPrivate, but I have had little success using PowerMockito to mock private method calls.

You do have a couple of possible moves:  Make the private methods protected (and then you can just use Mockito partial mocking to do what you want to do here), or refactor the code so that you do not have these private methods and can @Mock the other object and thus have full mocking control over public calls.  I have no idea what other constraints you are working under, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Ya I tired the latest version of Mockito and it had no problem with mocking private methods with returns, its just when they are voids. However the suppress(Method) allowed me to move over the private setter methods.